# why garbage collector doesnot destroy spring container

Tags: java, spring, garbage-collection

I am loading my spring context within my class as follows:

```
public class Loader {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        final ConfigurableApplicationContext context =
            new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
                new String[] { serializationSpringContextPath }
            );

        System.out.println("main over");    
    }
}
```

Event after main method is complete context is still alive .How come the garbage collector is not 
collecting it?

Comment: the program prints "main over" and is still running

Comment: That means that some thread is started by the loaded context. The JVM doesn't exit when main returns. It exits when all the non-daemon threads are done.

Comment: yes Looks like,How can i get a referece to that thread?

Comment: How could I know? I can't guess what your context contains. I'm not an extra-lucid wizard. What would you do with such a reference anyway?

Comment: @JBNizet plz check my complete use case here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769167/memory-leak-with-spring-configurableapplicationcontext

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create a `ConfigurableApplicationContext` then you need to call `close()` on it when you're finished with it. Otherwise the beans in the context, and the context itself, will not release any resources that are being held - including threads.

For example, any beans in your context that create non-daemon threads will prevent your program from shutting down.

Incidentally, this has nothing to do with garbage collection. A java program will terminate as soon as all non-daemon threads have finished executing, GC or no GC.

Comment: Thanks for that . i have posted my complete use case here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769167/memory-leak-with-spring-configurableapplicationcontext