# memory leak with spring ConfigurableApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

```
public class Tasker{
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context  ;

    public void load(){
          context = = loadSpringContext();
    }

    pulic void doSomething(){
      //do something
    }

    public  void close(){
       context.close();
    }
}


public class Caller extends Thread {

  public void run(){
    Tasker tasker = new Tasker();
       try{
         tasker.load();
         tasker.doSomething();
       }finally(){
         tasket.close();
       }
  }

}

//sample driver code which is not in my control
Caller caller = new Caller()
caller.start();
caller.stop();
```

Now the problem is if somone calls kills thread my Spring context is never closed and its a memeory leak.How can i prevent it?

Note: i cant change driver code.

Comment: Thread's are not typically "killed" in the JVM.  The Thread.stop() method is deprecated and should not be used.  How is it that "someone" is able to prevent `tasket.close()` from being invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.stop` is evil and heavily deprecated and should never, ever be used. It gives the thread no chance to clean up after itself. In your case, it's likely that the `Tasker.close` method is never being called, since the Thread stop *immediately*. You can verify this by putting in some log statements in your `Tasker` methods that print out when things actually occur.

It's vastly preferably to use `Thread.interrupt` instead, and for the code in that thread to check for the interrupt periodically.

If this is from calling code that you can't control then you're out of luck, since such code means you can't control your contexts' lifecycles properly.